# Getting data from an unknow data model

Tags: c#, templates

Okay, so I want to have a generic method that can read data from an unknown data class given a razor type property pointer.

I.E. I want to be able to pass in a string containing a template and a object and then extract the data from the object given the string in the template.

```
String template = "@Model.Basket";
var results = parse(template, data);
```

the parse method should have no knowledge of the specific model being passed to it, so its method signature should be something like:

```
public var parse(String template, object model)
```

where data is something like

```
public class Receipt
{
    public String Firstname { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDateTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean ReturnCustomer { get; set; }
    public LineItem[] Basket { get; set; }


    public class LineItem
    {
        public Product product { get; set; }
        public int Units { get; set; }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public String ProductName { get; set; }
            public double Cost { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case parse should return an array of line items, but if my template was equal to "@Model.Firstname" it should simply return a string containing the the name stored in that property.

Does anyone have any good ideas.

Note that for this given solution, I can not make use of the Razor engine as my templates are not in a format that the razor engine can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this, you want to look at the `System.Reflection` namespace - in particular, PropertyInfo. I'm not sure that it *is* a good idea, though.

Comment: I was thinking that reflection might be the only way. Why do you think it's not a good idea though?

Comment: I can't be sure that it's not a good idea without knowing your problem domain, but it seems to have the potential to become convoluted and unmaintainable. Perhaps investigating T4 templating might lead to a more manageable solution?

Comment: I had a look at T4 Templates and they won't work because when you create a template in VS it actually creates cs code behind file, so the template is precoded by VS. In my project I need users to be able to generate the templates in any application which I then want to interpret and fill at runtime.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Have you tried saving the templates to a given folder, then adding that folder to the RazorViewEngine.ViewLocationFormats ? (this is just an idea - I've not tried it)